# Running ArcGIS model at specified time or with delay?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, modelbuilder

I am looking to start running an ArcGIS model built in ModelBuilder in the future.

Start at a specific time.

or

Start in x hours.

or something similar.

When I leave the office I may have data processing in GDAL that I know will run for 3-6 hours.

I then want to process the outputs in ModelBuilder but I need to set it to start in say 8 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that a model exported to Python will run without debugging and, depending on your model's complexity, that debugging effort could be considerable.

I would wrap your model into a very short Python script that consists of little more than [arcpy.ImportToolbox()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v0000005z000000).

For example, if you have a TestModel (without an alias) in C:\test\TestToolbox.tbx:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"C:\test\TestToolbox.tbx","temp")
arcpy.TestModel_temp(<any_parameters>)
```

You can then add this Python script (*.py) to your Scheduled Tasks of Windows.